# Object returning junk values after being returned in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to create a thread library. `MyThreadCreate` returns an object of type `MyThread`.  E.g.:

```
struct MyThread
{
   ucontext_t Context; 
   ThreadStatus Status;
   int ThreadId;
};

typedef struct MyThread MyThread;

void * MyThreadCreate(void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
{
  MyThread temp;
  char *stack;
  stack = (char *)malloc(8192*sizeof(char));
  ucontext_t tempContext;
  if (getcontext(&tempContext) == -1)
  temp->ThreadId = 0;
  tempContext.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
  tempContext.uc_stack.ss_size = 8192*sizeof(char);
  tempContext.uc_link = NULL;
  makecontext(&tempContext,(void(*)(void))start_funct,1, args);
  temp->Context = tempContext;
  temp->Status = READY;
  temp->ParentThread = currentThread;
  temp->ThreadId = NEW_THREAD_ID++;
  return temp;
}
```

In my `client.c`, I call as follows.

```
MyThread T;
T = (MyThread)MyThreadCreate(t0, (void *)n2);
MyThreadJoin(T);
```

In MyThreadJoin, when I check the value of threadId of T, i get a random value.

```
void MyThreadJoin(MyThread thread); //defintion for MyThreadJoin
```

**Updated part:
When I try to return an object named MyThread, i get a segmentation fault immediately after I call MyThreadCreate.
Also, note that I'm including a header file(I cant change that) which contains the following definition.
typedef void *MyThread
So, the code works only when I return void * for MyThreadCreate and not when MyThread. But even though the code works fine, I'm not able to get the threadId in this case. 
Can some1 tell me where I've gone wrong.**

When I tried to keep the return value of MyTHreadCreate as MyThread, it throws segmentation fault. So I made it into void * and i'm able to get the object and then use it to call a MyThreadJoin, but there I get a junk value for MyThreadId. What is that I'm missing.

Comment: None of the code here looks like it should cause a segmentation fault.  What are you doing with `t1` after the code you've shown?

Comment: Your 'constructor' code does not initialize the `Context`.  This won't matter if you don't use it before it is initialized separately, but it might lead to problems if you do.  Otherwise, I agree with Joshua.  (Note that I added the missing semicolon after the structure declaration.  I also added the `typedef` line since in C, you cannot use just `MyThread` unless there _is_ a `typedef` like that.  C++ allows it (and also allows the `typedef`).  But plain C does not recognize the type name `MyStruct` simply because you defined `struct MyStruct`.)

Comment: Please paste your actual code.  Replace `args...` with the actual argument list.

Comment: Have pasted the actual code.

Comment: You returning a struct as a void pointer.

Comment: Your compiler should issue a warning for returning a `struct` as a `void *`...

Comment: Does C really compile this, allow returning a struct *value* as a void *pointer*? Anyway, enable warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc) and fix them, as the first step.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. I am not sure because there is something happening because of the typedef mentioned in the header file. There are no warnings thrown while compiling, only segmentation faults while running with MyThread as the return value.

Answer (score 4):

The problem boils down to:

```
void * MyThreadCreate(...)
{
    MyThread temp;
    // manipulate temp
    return temp;
}
```

Outside code is only expecting a `void *` on the stack so only the first `sizeof(void *)` bytes of `temp` are preserved.  Try to access anything beyond that and you're getting random garbage on the stack.

Instead, your function should return `MyThread` like this:

```
MyThread MyThreadCreate(...)
{
    MyThread temp;
    // manipulate temp
    return temp;
}
```

Or, if you must return a `void *` to interface with some other code, then you must allocate the return value on the heap:

```
void * MyThreadCreate(...)
{
    MyThread *temp = malloc(sizeof(MyThread));
    // manipulate temp
    return temp;
}
```

But that is a memory leak waiting to happen, so I would return the struct by value if possible.

Comment: I've updated the question with my problem keeping it as MyThread. Can you shed some light on where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I added the middle block of code showing exactly how it should look.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to mark this as the answer. The last part is how it should be. There is a thread Exit function which is also called everytime the program terminates and that frees up memory.

Thanks a lot.

In my code, I've another struct MyThread_t which is actually my structure. MyThread is basically void * in my application. Just realized it late. Sorry for the confusion.